# Picasso image is present but not shown

Tags: java, android, imageview, picasso

i need your help guys with picasso library , i'm trying to load multiple images from firebase with picasso , the problem is
The image is present but not shown. which means that when i click on the blank case , i can display it somewhere else , and when i switch activity and come back images will display.

The url of the images is valid , my internet permission is on.

Here is the code :

```
 public void loadImageInBackground(UnderProducts underProd, final String tableImage, final ImageView imageUnderProdTop) {



    target = new Target() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
            Log.e("picassoLoad","bitmap preparation");

        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap arg0, Picasso.LoadedFrom arg1) {
           Log.e("PicassoLoadedFrom",arg1.name());
            Log.e("PicassoItem",arg0.toString());
            if(tableImage.equals("normal"))
            {
                imageTable.add(arg0);
            }else if(tableImage.equals("top"))
            {
                imageTopTable.add(arg0);
            }

            if(imageUnderProdTop!=null)
            {

                imageUnderProdTop.setImageBitmap(arg0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
            Log.e("picasso","bitmap failed");
            Log.e("picassoError",e.getMessage());
        }


    };
    Picasso.get()
            .load(underProd.getImgId()).into(target);

}
```

The table of bitmap images size is 0

```
ImageView[] imgTab = {top_1_img, top_2_img, top_3_img, top_4_img, top_5_img, top_6_img, top_7_img, top_8_img};
                   for(int x=0;x<top_eight.size();x++) {

                       loadImageInBackground(top_eight.get(x),"top",imgTab[x]);
                   }
                   if(o<70)
                   {
                       o+=10;
                       anim.setProgress(o);
                   }
                   Toast.makeText(Accueil.this,String.valueOf(imageTopTable.size()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   for(int l=0;l<imageTopTable.size();l++)
                   {
                       imgTab[l].setImageBitmap(imageTopTable.get(l));

                   }
```

My Build.Gradle file config :

```
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.hasardpunk.lista"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.michaelmuenzer.android:ScrollableNumberPicker:0.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
//implementation 'com.github.onlylemi:mapview:v1.0'
implementation project(':library')

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
```

}

Comment: is there any logs/error that you can share?

Comment: I actualy get no error , that's the problem , i have nothing that indicate that image is not loaded

Comment: are you sure all your variable values are still there in the memory while switching from activity to activity  ?

Comment: No , i don't think so , what code should i add ?

Comment: If this is the case then make your variable static/global according to your use-case though it is not considered a good practise but you can give a try and later on make your code more clean.